# how to figure out the coordinates of a point 2 units away?

Tags: math

Say I have 2 tiles in a grid.

```
Tile1[x,y] //stationary thing

Tile2[x,y] //movable thing
```

Im treating them as circles each with a radius of 1 and trying to perform collision interaction.

I can determine distance and therefore IF theyre touching, but am stumped on determining something else (I dont know the word of the thing Im looking for). I want to be able to say "find a new point [x,y] that lies on the line Tile1->Tile2 but is 2.01 units away from Tile1".

I think I need to find the angle, then the hypotenuse length, and figure that hypotenuses length percent of 2, then multiply THAT number by x and y difference. Is there a better (or correct) way to do it?

Comment: Should be on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lNewPoint.x = Tile1.x + (Tile2.x - Tile1.x) * 2.01 / d;
lNewPoint.y = Tile1.y + (Tile2.y - Tile1.y) * 2.01 / d;
```

Where `d` is the distance from `Tile1` to `Tile2`

A second collinear (the term you were looking for) point can be found at:

```
lNewPoint.x = Tile1.x - (Tile2.x - Tile1.x) * 2.01 / d;
lNewPoint.y = Tile1.y - (Tile2.y - Tile1.y) * 2.01 / d;
```

The solution assumes `Tile1` and `Tile2` are not identical. In that case `d == 0` and the solution is a circle with `Tile1` at its center and radius `2.01`.

Comment: I knew there was a word for it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the hypotenuse length; once you have the angle (via `atan2()`, you can plug that into `sin()` and `cos()` to get the offset for unit distance, then multiply each by 2.01.